# Flutter Navigator getting wrong values from Navigator.pop

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I am using Navigator in flutter and I have a screen with the following code:

```
    tempResultHolder = await Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
      MenuOverlay(
          studentTest: widget.studentTest,
          context: context,
          currentQuestionIndex: currentQuestion - 1,
          currentSectionIndex: currentSection),
    );
    debugPrint('String got from menu: $tempResultHolder');
```

The popping code from menuOverlay is:

```
          onTap() {
             debugPrint('Sending from menu: $outerIndex,${innerIndex + 1}');
             Navigator.pop(context, '$outerIndex,$innerIndex');
          }
```

The console output is:

> Sending from menu: 2,4 
>   String got from menu: 2,3
>   
> Please tell me, if I can do something to get the right data. If the outerIndex is odd, i am getting 1 more in inner index: For odd index:
>   Sending from menu: 1,4
>   String got from menu: 1,4

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I was using async on onTap() in main screen where i was navigating to the overlay screen. I removed it and everything worked fine.